# How can I track/color seperate shapes generated using perlin noise?

Tags: algorithm, indexing, graphics, processing, perlin-noise

So I have created a 2D animation that consists of 3D Perlin noise where the X & Y axes are the pixel positions on the matrix/screen and the Z axis just counts up over time. I then apply a threshold so it only shows solid shapes unlike the cloud type pattern of the normal noise. In effect it creates a forever moving fluid animation like so https://i.imgur.com/J9AqY5s.gifv

I have been trying to think of a way I can track and maybe index the different shapes so I can have them all be different colours. I'm tried looping over the image and flood filling each shape but this only works for one frame as it doesn't track which shape is which and how they grow and shrink.

I think there must be a way to do something like this because if I had a colouring pencil and each frame on a piece of paper I would be able to colour and track each blob and combine colours when two blobs join. I just can't figure out how to do this programmatically. The nature in which Perlin-noise works and since the shapes aren't defined objects I find it difficult to wrap my head around how I would index them.

Hopefully, my explanation has been sufficient, any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. The best thing I can tell you to do is to try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those steps on one at a time. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [mcve] along with a specific technical question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your current algorithm effectively marks every pixel in a frame as part of a blob or part of the background.  Let's say you have a second frame buffer that can hold a color for every pixel location.  As you noted, you can use flood fill on the blob/background buffer to find all the pixels that belong to a blob.

For the first frame, assign colors to each blob you find and save them in the color buffer.

For the second (and each subsequent) frame, you can again use flood fill on the blob/background buffer to determine all the pixels that belong to a discrete blob.  Look up the colors corresponding to those each of those pixels from the color buffer (which represents the colors from the last frame) and build a histogram of all the colors you find.

The histogram will contain some of the pixels of the background color (because the blob may have moved or grown into an area that was background).

But since the blobs move smoothly, many of the pixels that are part of a given blob this frame will have been be part of the same blob on the last frame.  So if your histogram has just one non-background color, that's the color you would use.

If the histogram contains only the background color, this is a new blob and you can assign it a new color.

If the histogram contains two (or more) blob colors, then two (or more) blobs have merged, and you can blend their colors (perhaps in proportion to their histogram counts with correspond to their areas).

This trick will be to do all this efficiently.  The algorithm I've outlined here gives the idea.  An actual implementation may not literally build histograms and might take recalculate each pixel color frame scratch on every frame.